# NoSuchElementException in selenium while making Instagram bot

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I'm trying to make a bot that makes Instagram accounts by itself. A few minutes before, I was making it and it was working perfectly. However, the second time I ran it, I had this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akshatverma/PycharmProjects/wantfollowers/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    _email = browser_.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input")
  File "/Users/akshatverma/PycharmProjects/wantfollowers/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Users/akshatverma/PycharmProjects/wantfollowers/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Users/akshatverma/PycharmProjects/wantfollowers/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/akshatverma/PycharmProjects/wantfollowers/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input
```

This is my code:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/No66i.png]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

May be you need apply some waits. And instead of Absolute use Relative xpaths.

Apply Explicit waits like below and try :

```
# Imports Required
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

browser_.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

browser_.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Sign up']").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser_,30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@aria-label='Username']")))

email = browser_.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Username']")
email.send_keys("Sample Text")
```